# Multiple Forms in JSP ResultSet, get data in Servlet

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets

Following is a form in a resultSet loop. So, there might be multiple forms according to range of results.

```
/* RESULT SET LOOP STARTED with `i` as iterator running from 1 to 5 */ 
<form action='Jaga' method='post' >
    <input name='input-<%=i%>' />
</form>
/* RESULT SET LOOP ENDED */
```

So, on form-submission, Jaga Servlet receives information. How do i get to know which 'input-iterator' combination was used from which form.

```
request.getParameter('here');
```

What do i fill in-place of 'here' in Jaga Servlet to get correct input box value from correct form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at 
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)

You can see that it returns a String or null if parameter doesn't exist, so you can simply make a for loop and check for the first not null return . Something like:

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)

    if(request.getParameter("input-"+i)!=null)
        // handle stuff
```

**EDIT:** For getting the parameter names, try:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Enumeration<String> parameter = request.getParameterNames();
        while(parameter.hasMoreElements())
            out.println(parameter.nextElement());
```

Comment: problem is that 'iterator' can be anything: text or number: Its stored as a unique Id in database and retrieved using resultset. Then, this Id is used to create a unique element, for e.g. name='`input-<%=Id%>`'. I want to know what input box Id was used. I want to get Id variable to reach in Servlet